# Calculate coordinates when having a rectangle and matrix

Tags: javascript, math, svg, transform

If I have a SVG rectangle with

```
[x1,y1,x2,y2] = [ 456.079, 402.645, 514.841, 527.925 ]
```

and its SVG matrix

```
[0, 1, -1, 0, 58.7617, 0]
```

How can I calculate `x, y, w, h` of the rectangle?

Comment: how are the values related?

Comment: with the matrix [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  then x is the left position: x=x1, y is the  top position y=y1, w is width of the rectangle w =x2-x1, h is height of the rectangle h = y2-y1

Comment: wha do you have six values in the matrix (looks more like a vector ...)?

Comment: @NinaScholz its direct 2D homogenuous 3x3 transform matrix the last 3 elements are implicitly `(0,0,1)` that is how SVG defines it as there is no projection in it ... IIRC to transform vertexes you just need to multiply `position' = matrix*position`

Comment: this is the matrix stored in pdf file

Comment: @ThiPhạm btw you should add the SVG rectangle as code (just copy the SVG as text no need for whole SVG just the RECT or may be even parrent G tag if the matrix is in there)  so others are not confused and not adding invalid close votes (you got 2 just now)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is direct 2D homogenuous 3x3 transform matrix where the last 3 missing elements are implicitly `(0,0,1)` as there is no projection in SVG. Its basically a 2D version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214).

So you need to implement 3x3 matrix * 3D vector multiplication V' = M*V where matrix `M` is your 6 values + `(0,0,1)`  and 3D vector `V` is `(x,y,w=1)` the result is (x',y',w) where you can ignore the `w'`. So when written as code (taken from mine C++ SVG decoder/encoder I wrote few years ago) to transform vertexes just do this:

```cpp
x'=M[4]+(M[0]*x)+(M[2]*y);
y'=M[5]+(M[1]*x)+(M[3]*y);
```

If you have also scale present then:

```cpp
x'=M[4]+scalex*((M[0]*x)+(M[2]*y));
y'=M[5]+scaley*((M[1]*x)+(M[3]*y));
```

Where:

```cpp
M[6]={ 0, 1, -1, 0, 58.7617, 0 };
```

Also if you want to transform vectors (or sizes like width,height,radius) instead of vertexes then the `w=0` so the code ignores offset:

```cpp
x'=(M[0]*x)+(M[2]*y);
y'=(M[1]*x)+(M[3]*y);
```

If you have also scale present then:

```cpp
x'=scalex*((M[0]*x)+(M[2]*y));
y'=scaley*((M[1]*x)+(M[3]*y));
```

so transform position `(x1,y1)` with offset and `(x2,y2)` without (as its the width,height).

```cpp
x=M[4]+(M[0]*x1)+(M[2]*y1);
y=M[5]+(M[1]*x1)+(M[3]*y1);
w=     (M[0]*x2)+(M[2]*y2);
h=     (M[1]*x2)+(M[3]*y2);
```

In case your SVG object parents has more matrices you need to apply them in order too.

Comment: thanks, it's very helpful, and how can I find the angle?

Comment: @ThiPhạm its in the matrix ... IIRC its one of these `atan2(M[1],M[0])` or `atan2(M[2],M[0])` my bet its the latter one. The matrix contains 2 basis vectors (one for each axis) and offset I just do not remember if its stored in columns or rows and too lazy to analyze/reverse my old code...

Comment: I think it's should be atan2(-M[1],M[0]) or atan2(M[2],M[0])

Comment: @ThiPhạm depends on your coordinate system ... if your axises are x goes right and y up then no negation so most likely `atan2(M[2],M[0])` just try and see if the computed angle matches your SVG view

Comment: one more thing, what happens if [x1,y1,x2,y2] = [ 456.079, 402.645, 514.841, 527.925 ] is the result of the rectangle after rotated, can I find the original x, y?

Comment: @Stevenlee in svg the stuff in `<rect ...` is already in its local axis aligned coordinates. Each matrix applied to it (from each parent object that has matrix defined) converts those from the parent local coordinates into global ones (or its next parrent local coordinates). After all matrices applied the resulting coordinates are transformed by view into screen coordinates.  So what exactly you mean by original coordinates? If you want to transfer some screen coordinate into some object local coordinates then you just multiply by inverse matrices instead ...